# Recursive animation matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, physics

I want to animate some time propagation of a wavefunction. But I don't want to calculate all time steps every time because it takes a huge amount of time but take the previous value of the wavefunction as initial value. I don't know how to realize this with `animation.FuncAnimation`.
That's what I thought of:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

wavefunction_0 = some array 

def next_wavefunction(wavefunction_init): 
    wavefunction = time_propagation(Psi = wavefunction_init)
    return wavefunction

def animate(framenumber, wavefunction, surf):
    if framenumber == 0:
        wavefunction = wavefunction_0
    else: 
        wavefunction = next_wavefunction(wavefunction)
    ax.clear()
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.reshape(np.abs(wavefunction), (space_shape)), rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0,  antialiased=False, cmap='jet', edgecolor='none')
    return surf, wavefunction

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(wavefunction, surf),
                              interval=200, blit=False)
```

At the moment it is not working since `fargs = wavefunction` but wavefunction is a return value of `animate(...)`. Is it possible to take the return value of animate and pass it as `fargs`?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try either of the solutions in my answer?

Comment: @WilliamMiller I will look at it not later than next week!

Comment: Did you get around to looking at this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib expects that the `animate` function passed to [`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) returns a list of `artists`, as such it is not possible (at least to my understanding) to return non-artists like

```py
return surf, wavefunction
```

So even if you pass `wavefunction` into `animate`, you would not be able to return the mutated array. Unless you can refactor the code into a manner such that the array for the current frame can be calculated without information from the previous frame you cannot use this approach.

There are two ways you could get around this, one is to use a global variable to store the wavefunction array and mutate it as needed, that way changes made in the function persist beyond the end of the function. For demonstration, here is an example of this implementation which is slightly simpler than a changing wavefunction in 3 dimensions,

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

n = 100
wf = np.zeros((n,2))

def next_wf():
    global wf
    offset = wf[0,0] + 0.1
    wf[:,0] = np.linspace(offset, np.pi*4+offset, wf.shape[0])
    wf[:,1] = np.sin(wf[:,0])

def animate(frame):
    next_wf()
    plt.cla()
    plot, = plt.plot(wf[:,0], wf[:,1])
    return plot,

next_wf()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=25)
```

This will create an animation like the following

[image]

However, it should be noted that using global variables is explicitly advised against by the [Variables and Scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#more-about-scope-crossing-boundaries) page of the documentation,

> Note that it is usually very bad practice to access global variables from inside functions, and even worse practice to modify them. This makes it difficult to arrange our program into logically encapsulated parts which do not affect each other in unexpected ways. If a function needs to access some external value, we should pass the value into the function as a parameter. [...]

In a simple, self contained script it is unlikely to cause harm but in more complicated code it can be detrimental. The more 'proper' way to do this is to wrap the entire thing in a `class`, i.e.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

class waveanim:
    def __init__(self):
        n = 100
        self.wf = np.zeros((n,2))
        self.next_wf()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, self.animate, interval=25, blit=True)

        anim.save('./animation.gif', writer='imagemagick')

    def next_wf(self):
        offset = self.wf[0,0] + 0.1
        self.wf[:,0] = np.linspace(offset, np.pi*4+offset, self.wf.shape[0])
        self.wf[:,1] = np.sin(self.wf[:,0])

    def animate(self, frame):
        self.next_wf()
        plt.cla()
        plot, = plt.plot(self.wf[:,0], self.wf[:,1])
        return plot,

waveanim()
```

Which gives the same result as above.